# what does it mean by TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem during a react development..... it is showing this error in browser console. whats that means? and how to solve it ? ........

```js
react.development.js:1545 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1545:1)
    at BrowserRouter (utils.js:439:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16218:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:19984:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21505:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27344:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26471:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26383:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26355:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25767:1)
```

Comment: As error saying `Cannot read properties of null` that means one of your variable or method is `null`. Next time  paste your code also in question.

Comment: you should provide some more information about your code

Answer (score 0):

You should use if statement to access to useRef's current value